# Java command not found

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to get the java command to work on my computer. Whenever I try to use it, I get the error "'java' is not recognized as an internal or..."

**What I've done**
So far I've traced the issue through my system environment variables, which has a variable PATH that links to "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" or javapath for short.

There are 3 files in the javapath folder, and if you click on them a popup says: [image]

But when I examine the properties of the shortcut and click "open folder location" it sends me to the right place (?? what is this).

Just in case, I tried to recreate the shortcut; I called it java2 and it now works (opens a command box for a split second and closes) when I click on it. However, testing it in command prompt with the line "java2 -version" returns "'java2' is not recognized as an internal or external..."

**Details**
I just installed java 8, and I've verified that it was installed correctly

I'm running a 64 bit windows 7 OS

Comment: you should add the `\bin` directory inside jdk folder. it's ideally `C:/java_folder/jdk_version/bin' - The point is you need `bin` folder to be added to PATH. Remove the other things you have added and then see what happens. Also, your commands should be `javac myfile.java` for compiling and `java myclassfilename` for executing it. Is there anything you have done differently?

Comment: I don't know what you did, but for your terminal to recognize java as a process it needs to know of a location that contains java.exe, which you need to add that location to the PATH variable, so like C:/program_files/java/blahblah/bin something like that

Comment: PATH is a system environment variable, currently it's linking to the "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" I explained above

Comment: @hagubear For testing purposes, the only command I've used is "java -version". As for the JDK, I have a jre_version instead. Also, the PATH variable links to a folder with shortcuts to the jre_version... that's just how it was. I don't see how it could cause a problem, and tried linking it directly with the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked your environment variables for Windows? When you installed the JDK/JRE the directory should have been added to the PATH variable. The directory added needs to contain the java.exe executable. It should be located in  **C:\Program Files\Java** or something like that if you installed it using the default settings. Once you find that directory find the bin directory inside it.

In order to check that:

- Right click My Computer and hit Properties
- On the left side hit Advanced System Settings
- Hit the Advanced tab and then Environment Variables down at the bottom
- Find the PATH variable and then hit edit. Confirm that the location of the JDK /bin directory is there, if it is not then add it.

Also, if the JAVA_HOME variable isn't already set, [this may be a good idea](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows).

Comment: My path variable contains the link "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath", which contains shortcuts called "java.exe", "javaw.exe", and "javaws.exe", these shortcuts are linked to their counterparts in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin". This doesn't seem to be the problem, I've tried linking directly to the bin folder with no avail

Comment: IMHO, I would just go with adding the C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin directory to your path instead of shortcuts. That should work since java.exe is in that directory. I'd try these changes, exit the command prompt and then try again.

Comment: ... Exiting the command prompt, that was the problem. Thank-you, I've been working on this for hours. (it also only works when the path is set directly to the /bin folder)

Comment: Glad you got it! Every time you make a change to the PATH variable  or add other environment variables you need to restart the command prompt so it can load up the environment again.